# Definition of "Integration"

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, terminology, riemann-integration

Can I call it "Integration" if I solve a Riemann integral by calculating the area under the curve using the areas of known geometrical shapes (assuming they exist for such a curve)? Or can I only call it "Integration" if I evaluate the Riemann integral using anti-derivatives?

Context: an exam question said "Evaluate this using integration"

Comment: The second one can be called integration, that's for sure. I think we can argue about the first though.

Comment: So does "integration" mean evaluating an integral generally - or using the method of antiderivatives only?

Comment: It is both. However you said that you summed up areas of known geometrical shapes which might not be considered as integration (It's opinion based so I can't give you a real answer). For me integration is either that anti-derivatives method or an infinite sum of rectangles.

Comment: The "summing areas of known geometric shapes under the curve" is also called "quadratures" and it's traditionally how the integration was done before the advancement of calculus. Newton-Leibniz formula could be called integration, but considering it has a very limited application, I wouldn't mix the concepts like that. Searching for a primitive and integrating are very different activities

Comment: Haha, I missed that last sentence. In that case, use whatever you want to, since whoever created the question didn't bother with clarification

Comment: I would agree that the question phrased as "using integration" precludes using areas to find the answer.